# Exception in a loop

Tags: oracle, loops, exception

```
BEGIN
for i in 1..5 loop
        select n.id_naprawy
        INTO r_identyfikator_naprawy
        from naprawy n
        where n.id_naprawy = 1; 
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Nieprawidlowa lista napraw '); 
        RETURN;
END LOOP;
END;
```

WHEN - wrong syntax, When I add loop I got an error. What should I do?

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand and won't get you answers any faster. It's also rather impolite to come here and SHOUT at us when you're asking us for free help to solve your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need altogether `BEGIN..EXCEPTION..END` as follows:

```
BEGIN
for i in 1..5 loop
BEGIN -- this
        select n.id_naprawy
        INTO r_identyfikator_naprawy
        from naprawy n
        where n.id_naprawy = 1; 
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Nieprawidlowa lista napraw '); 
        RETURN;
END; -- this
END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: You can accept the answer if it solved your issue so that question is marked as resolved.